# Why is the sticky header not smooth?

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a table that has a sticky header when scrolling. Everything works, but for some reason this title when scrolling jerks. On mobile devices, it is very noticeable.....................................................

`translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` - use,

`willChange: transform, opacity, scroll-position` - use on scroll

How to achieve smoothness in this case?

Example, please

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('thead').length > 0 && $(this).find('th').length > 0) {
      // Clone <thead>
      var $w = $(window),
        $t = $(this),
        $thead = $t.find('thead').clone(),
        $col = $t.find('thead, tbody').clone();

      // Add class, remove margins, reset width and wrap table
      $t
        .addClass('sticky-enabled')
        .css({
          margin: 0,
          width: '100%'
        }).wrap('<div class="sticky-wrap" />');

      if ($t.hasClass('overflow-y')) $t.removeClass('overflow-y').parent().addClass('overflow-y');

      // Create new sticky table head (basic)
      $t.after('<table class="sticky-thead" />');

      // If <tbody> contains <th>, then we create sticky column and intersect (advanced)
      if ($t.find('tbody th').length > 0) {
        $t.after('<table class="sticky-col" /><table class="sticky-intersect" />');
      }

      // Create shorthand for things
      var $stickyHead = $(this).siblings('.sticky-thead'),
        $stickyCol = $(this).siblings('.sticky-col'),
        $stickyInsct = $(this).siblings('.sticky-intersect'),
        $stickyWrap = $(this).parent('.sticky-wrap');

      $stickyHead.append($thead);

      $stickyCol
        .append($col)
        .find('thead th:gt(0)').remove()
        .end()
        .find('tbody td').remove();

      $stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>' + $t.find('thead th:first-child').html() + '</th></tr></thead>');

      // Set widths
      var setWidths = function() {
          $t
            .find('thead th').each(function(i) {
              $stickyHead.find('th').eq(i).width($(this).width());
            })
            .end()
            .find('tr').each(function(i) {
              $stickyCol.find('tr').eq(i).height($(this).height());
            });

          // Set width of sticky table head
          $stickyHead.width($t.width());

          // Set width of sticky table col
          $stickyCol.find('th').add($stickyInsct.find('th')).width($t.find('thead th').width())
        },
        repositionStickyHead = function() {
          // Return value of calculated allowance
          var allowance = calcAllowance();

          // Check if wrapper parent is overflowing along the y-axis
          if ($t.height() > $stickyWrap.height()) {
            // If it is overflowing (advanced layout)
            // Position sticky header based on wrapper scrollTop()
            if ($stickyWrap.scrollTop() > 0) {
              // When top of wrapping parent is out of view
              var ss = $stickyWrap.scrollTop();
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                transform: 'translate3d(0px,' + ss + 'px' + ', 0px)',
                willChange: 'transform, opacity, scroll-position'
              });
            } else {
              // When top of wrapping parent is in view
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 0,
                transform: 'translate3d(0px,' + 0 + ', 0px)',
                willChange: 'auto'
              });
            }
          } else {
            // If it is not overflowing (basic layout)
            // Position sticky header based on viewport scrollTop
            if ($w.scrollTop() > $t.offset().top && $w.scrollTop() < $t.offset().top + $t.outerHeight() - allowance) {
              // When top of viewport is in the table itself
              var abcd = window.pageYOffset - $t.offset().top;
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                transform: 'translate3d(0px,' + abcd + 'px' + ', 0px)',
                willChange: 'transform, opacity, scroll-position'
              });
            } else {
              // When top of viewport is above or below table
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 0,
                transform: 'translate3d(0px,' + 0 + ', 0px)',
                willChange: 'auto'
              });
            }
          }
        },
        repositionStickyCol = function() {
          if ($stickyWrap.scrollLeft() > 0) {
            // When left of wrapping parent is out of view
            $stickyCol.add($stickyInsct).css({
              opacity: 1,
              left: $stickyWrap.scrollLeft()
            });
          } else {
            // When left of wrapping parent is in view
            $stickyCol
              .css({
                opacity: 0
              })
              .add($stickyInsct).css({
                left: 0
              });
          }
        },
        calcAllowance = function() {
          var a = 0;
          // Calculate allowance
          $t.find('tbody tr:lt(3)').each(function() {
            a += $(this).height();
          });

          // Set fail safe limit (last three row might be too tall)
          // Set arbitrary limit at 0.25 of viewport height, or you can use an arbitrary pixel value
          if (a > $w.height() * 0.25) {
            a = $w.height() * 0.25;
          }

          // Add the height of sticky header
          a += $stickyHead.height();
          return a;
        };

      setWidths();

      $t.parent('.sticky-wrap').on('scroll', function() {
        repositionStickyHead();
        repositionStickyCol();
      });

      $w.on('load', setWidths);
      $w.on('resize', function() {
        setWidths();
        repositionStickyHead();
        repositionStickyCol();
      });
      $w.on('scroll', repositionStickyHead);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";
}

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7c8d87;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

a {
  color: #31bc86;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #7c8d87;
}

.container>header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}

.container>header h1 {
  font-size: 2.625em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.container>header span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}


/* To Navigation Style */

.codrops-top {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.69em;
  line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}

.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
  font-family: 'codropsicons';
  margin: 0 4px;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.codrops-icon-drop:before {
  content: "\e001";
}

.codrops-icon-prev:before {
  content: "\e004";
}


/* Demo Buttons Style */

.codrops-demos {
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.codrops-demos a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.7em 1.1em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #31bc86;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.codrops-demos a:hover,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
  border-color: #7c8d87;
  color: #7c8d87;
}

.related {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
  .codrops-icon span {
    display: none;
  }
}

.component {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 3em;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.component .filler {
  font-family: "Blokk", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

td.err {
  background-color: #e992b9;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

th {
  background-color: #31bc86;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tbody th {
  background-color: #2ea879;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(2n-1) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(129, 208, 177, .3);
}


/* For appearance */

.sticky-wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-col,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0s ease;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  z-index: 50;
  width: auto;
  /* Prevent table from stretching to full size */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead {
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.1em -0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  /* Force stretch */
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 150;
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect th {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #eee;
}

.sticky-wrap td,
.sticky-wrap th {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Not needed for sticky header/column functionality */

td.user-name {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.sticky-wrap.overflow-y {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="component">
    <h2>Basic usage</h2>
    <p>This is a basic usage example. Scroll down to see the sticky table header in action. And of course, multiple instances are supported. Tables are pre-populated with random user data retrieved from the <a href="http://randomuser.me/" title="Random User Generator">Random User Generator</a>.</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">gary coleman</td>
          <td class="user-email">gary.coleman21@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(398)-332-5385</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(888)-677-3719</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">rose parker</td>
          <td class="user-email">rose.parker16@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(293)-873-2247</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(216)-889-4933</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">chloe nelson</td>
          <td class="user-email">chloe.nelson18@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(957)-213-3499</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(207)-516-4474</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">eric bell</td>
          <td class="user-email">eric.bell16@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(897)-762-9782</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(565)-627-3002</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">douglas hayes</td>
          <td class="user-email">douglas.hayes92@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(231)-391-6269</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(790)-838-2130</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">cameron brown</td>
          <td class="user-email">cameron.brown32@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(204)-488-5204</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(508)-463-6811</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">nevaeh diaz</td>
          <td class="user-email">nevaeh.diaz99@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(436)-578-2946</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(906)-412-3302</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">kathy miller</td>
          <td class="user-email">kathy.miller62@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(724)-705-3555</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(764)-841-2531</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">susan king</td>
          <td class="user-email">susan.king88@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(774)-205-7754</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(639)-267-9728</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">jeffery ramirez</td>
          <td class="user-email">jeffery.ramirez83@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(723)-243-7706</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(172)-597-3422</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">gary coleman</td>
          <td class="user-email">gary.coleman21@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(398)-332-5385</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(888)-677-3719</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">rose parker</td>
          <td class="user-email">rose.parker16@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(293)-873-2247</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(216)-889-4933</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">chloe nelson</td>
          <td class="user-email">chloe.nelson18@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(957)-213-3499</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(207)-516-4474</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">eric bell</td>
          <td class="user-email">eric.bell16@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(897)-762-9782</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(565)-627-3002</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">douglas hayes</td>
          <td class="user-email">douglas.hayes92@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(231)-391-6269</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(790)-838-2130</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">cameron brown</td>
          <td class="user-email">cameron.brown32@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(204)-488-5204</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(508)-463-6811</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">nevaeh diaz</td>
          <td class="user-email">nevaeh.diaz99@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(436)-578-2946</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(906)-412-3302</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">kathy miller</td>
          <td class="user-email">kathy.miller62@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(724)-705-3555</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(764)-841-2531</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">susan king</td>
          <td class="user-email">susan.king88@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(774)-205-7754</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(639)-267-9728</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">jeffery ramirez</td>
          <td class="user-email">jeffery.ramirez83@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(723)-243-7706</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(172)-597-3422</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">gary coleman</td>
          <td class="user-email">gary.coleman21@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(398)-332-5385</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(888)-677-3719</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">rose parker</td>
          <td class="user-email">rose.parker16@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(293)-873-2247</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(216)-889-4933</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">chloe nelson</td>
          <td class="user-email">chloe.nelson18@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(957)-213-3499</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(207)-516-4474</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">eric bell</td>
          <td class="user-email">eric.bell16@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(897)-762-9782</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(565)-627-3002</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">douglas hayes</td>
          <td class="user-email">douglas.hayes92@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(231)-391-6269</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(790)-838-2130</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">cameron brown</td>
          <td class="user-email">cameron.brown32@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(204)-488-5204</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(508)-463-6811</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">nevaeh diaz</td>
          <td class="user-email">nevaeh.diaz99@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(436)-578-2946</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(906)-412-3302</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">kathy miller</td>
          <td class="user-email">kathy.miller62@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(724)-705-3555</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(764)-841-2531</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">susan king</td>
          <td class="user-email">susan.king88@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(774)-205-7754</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(639)-267-9728</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">jeffery ramirez</td>
          <td class="user-email">jeffery.ramirez83@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(723)-243-7706</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(172)-597-3422</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="filler">Curabitur placerat, nulla ultricies a, convallis pellentesque, justo nec eros. Fusce condimentum ante. Proin dapibus, felis fermentum orci molestie turpis id nulla ac nunc. Nunc dictum accumsan et, eros.</p>
    <p class="filler">Duis non mi odio, sagittis lorem. Sed aliquet in, convallis turpis. Nullam semper id, eleifend congue. Proin vel mauris rhoncus ac, tincidunt rutrum molestie, nunc justo, hendrerit metus nonummy at, ligula. Donec libero malesuada enim quis massa.</p>
    <p class="filler">Phasellus hendrerit tellus felis mollis luctus. Aenean aliquet. Aliquam commodo id, bibendum nulla ut lacus. Aliquam ultricies odio, fermentum ut, neque. Sed mattis. Pellentesque tellus.</p>
    <p class="filler">Cum sociis natoque penatibus et massa. Integer convallis ligula bibendum vel, nibh. Etiam congue fringilla turpis. Nullam erat eu mauris.</p>
    <p class="filler">Pellentesque facilisis sodales. Aenean commodo odio fermentum leo mollis consectetuer. Curabitur lobortis quis, venenatis lorem eget tempus purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

The same code on a [codepen](https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/QoyMpv).

Comment: Please **only** use external code sites if what you want to show cannot be achieved using StackOverflow's snippet functionality.

Comment: Sounds like the browser is using too much resources to render your sticky head. [Using `will-change` will harm your page performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) which is likely the issue you are facing. If you authored the above code yourself, you can try to optimize it to use less resource intensive operations.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because a heavy jQuery library + you are forcing browser to reflow every time `transform` fires.

Comment: don't use js to calculate the offset of an element, use either css sticky or use intersection observer to create a sticky header if css solution doesn't provide a good result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JavaScript for the sticky function use CSS [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/position) which is rendering way faster. It is [supported in most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7c8d87;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

    table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

td.err {
  background-color: #e992b9;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

th {
  background-color: #31bc86;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tbody th {
  background-color: #2ea879;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(2n-1) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(129, 208, 177, .3);
}

/* Use sticky on th and not on thead because of browser bugs (see caniuse.com) */
thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="component">
    <h2>Basic usage</h2>
    <p>This is a basic usage example. Scroll down to see the sticky table header in action. And of course, multiple instances are supported. Tables are pre-populated with random user data retrieved from the <a href="http://randomuser.me/" title="Random User Generator">Random User Generator</a>.</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">gary coleman</td>
          <td class="user-email">gary.coleman21@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(398)-332-5385</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(888)-677-3719</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">rose parker</td>
          <td class="user-email">rose.parker16@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(293)-873-2247</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(216)-889-4933</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">chloe nelson</td>
          <td class="user-email">chloe.nelson18@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(957)-213-3499</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(207)-516-4474</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">eric bell</td>
          <td class="user-email">eric.bell16@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(897)-762-9782</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(565)-627-3002</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">douglas hayes</td>
          <td class="user-email">douglas.hayes92@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(231)-391-6269</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(790)-838-2130</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="user-name">cameron brown</td>
          <td class="user-email">cameron.brown32@example.com</td>
          <td class="user-phone">(204)-488-5204</td>
          <td class="user-mobile">(508)-463-6811</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="filler">Curabitur placerat, nulla ultricies a, convallis pellentesque, justo nec eros. Fusce condimentum ante. Proin dapibus, felis fermentum orci molestie turpis id nulla ac nunc. Nunc dictum accumsan et, eros.</p>
    <p class="filler">Duis non mi odio, sagittis lorem. Sed aliquet in, convallis turpis. Nullam semper id, eleifend congue. Proin vel mauris rhoncus ac, tincidunt rutrum molestie, nunc justo, hendrerit metus nonummy at, ligula. Donec libero malesuada enim quis massa.</p>
    <p class="filler">Phasellus hendrerit tellus felis mollis luctus. Aenean aliquet. Aliquam commodo id, bibendum nulla ut lacus. Aliquam ultricies odio, fermentum ut, neque. Sed mattis. Pellentesque tellus.</p>
    <p class="filler">Cum sociis natoque penatibus et massa. Integer convallis ligula bibendum vel, nibh. Etiam congue fringilla turpis. Nullam erat eu mauris.</p>
    <p class="filler">Pellentesque facilisis sodales. Aenean commodo odio fermentum leo mollis consectetuer. Curabitur lobortis quis, venenatis lorem eget tempus purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by overflow table? What browser are you using? I just tested it in Edge, Chrome and Firefox and the result is the same as in your original answer, just smoother. The header scrolls with the page and stays at the top until you scroll past the table.

Comment: My table have got a horisontal scroll, but you table travels outside of content

Comment: I removed all of the JavaScript (including the part where the tables width is altered) for sake of clarity. You have to delete the `repositionStickyHead()` function and all of its references. Then add the CSS rule to `thead th` and this will make your table header sticky while scrolling smooth.

Comment: position sticky don't work, if wrapper have got overflow properties. In my example .sticky-wrap overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: Remove `overflow-y: hidden;` from `.sticky-wrap` and it will work. Why do you need to hide the overflow when you are always displaying the whole table anyway?